# Auto-Save fires `DocumentBeforeSave` event - How to circumvent this?

Tags: c#, vsto, office-addins

When a file is saved (on purpose) I would like to perform a certain action.
This all works with the following code:
`Application.DocumentBeforeSave += new word.ApplicationEvents4_DocumentBeforeSaveEventHandler(ThisAddIn_BeforeSave);`

There is only one problem, this event also fires when a change is made to the document and the 'Autorecover' function saves this change.

Is there a way to circumvent this action or at least detect if it was an auto-save?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I've managed to find the answer to this question on [**this**](https://theofficecontext.com/2011/05/04/auto-recovery-save-autosave-fires-off-the-documentbeforesave-event-in-word/) site.
Essentially, this makes use of the VBA properties of a Word application I assume.

```
object oBasic = Application.WordBasic;
object fIsAutoSave =
        oBasic.GetType().InvokeMember(
            "IsAutosaveEvent",
            BindingFlags.GetProperty,
            null, oBasic, null);
if (int.Parse(fIsAutoSave.ToString()) == 1)
    MessageBox.Show("Is AutoSave");
else
    MessageBox.Show("Is regular save");
```

This solution seems to work for office 2007 and up.